Are there technical limitations that prevent forwarding calls between devices over wifi?
I'm wondering if there are any restrictions placed on apps that would prevent audio forwarding for calls.
This is what I imagine:

You have two Android phones, phone A and phone B
Phone A has a sim card and is left in your host country connected to WiFi
Phone B does not have a sim card, and is with you when you travel to another country, but will have WiFi
When phone A receives a phone call, phone B will ring and you would be able to answer the call. Keep in mind this would happen over WiFi
You would also be able to make calls from phone B, and it would be routed via WiFi to phone A

What I've noticed when looking for apps is:

text forwarding and receiving is plentiful, tons of apps do this but not for calls
VNC apps such as TeamViewer or AnyDesk do not forward audio from phone B to phone A
There is a hardware solution for this, but it's subscription based ( https://www.glocalme.com/product/simbox/ )

There's been some interest in this topic, but no answers:

https://xdaforums.com/t/call-forwarding-to-no-sim-phone-help-pls.3448976/
Controlling phone and making calls remotely

This leads me to believe that this is not possible, but why?

Sounds to me that you are searching for a cellular-to-voip gateway running on Android. VoIP using SIP protocol is a standardized protocol for which you can  get apps on Android. So phone A would be the gateway and phone B the VoIP client that is connected via VPN to your home network. That way it should work and should be wy more stable that display forwarding solutions. I only have no experience with cellular-to-voip gateways.

@Robert You're absolutely correct. And with a bit of digging it lead me to this question -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71682235/how-can-i-bridge-phone-calls-to-voip unfortunately it looks like it hasn't been implemented yet either. But it's definitely on the right track!

It's looking like it's not feasible -  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91880/how-do-i-forward-incoming-calls-over-voip-to-another-client

@DaveChen, you should make that an answer and after a day, you can even tick it.  I ended up finding a provider with a plan that charges for calls and text when roaming, rather than a per day charge.  Text reception is free and wifi calling is free.  I have a voicemail message to tell them to call my other number.  And I dont answer the phone.  Actually, I am using one phone with a normal sim and an esim.
